# Run HTTP calls in `ThreadGroup` sequentially

Tags: jmeter

I have two http calls as follows:

The first is a `POST` call that returns an id and I write it to a file. In the second `GET` call, the written id is read from the file and processed.

But when I run the following, it says that the file should exist and be readable. So I'm guessing the file-read is happening before or together with the write-file.

Is there a way to make the read-file wait before trying to read? Or how to add a timer between them?

[image]

And this is the exception I'm getting:

```
2018-04-23 15:37:00,028 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File scenario1_accountreq.csv must exist and be readable
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:430) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:346) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:203) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:393) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:385) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:158) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Problem occurred when you are executing with 1 thread/user?

Comment: @user7294900 yes, 1 thread/user

Comment: Can you show how you write it to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JMeter Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) CSV Data Set Config is being executed **before** you write anything into a file:

> 1. Configuration elements
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler
> 5. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 7. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

So you will not be able to achieve what you're trying to achieve using CSV Data Set Config, consider using [CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead. Functions can be placed anywhere in the script and they're processed exactly where/when they are found, hopefully file will exist by that time. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

---

Also be aware that storing interim data in file will is extremely inefficient, causing high disk IO and potential [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), so I would recommend to avoid this step and use in-memory JMeter Variables instead.